# use if/else in knockout.js in order to render element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this loop:

```
<ul class="media-list chat-list" data-bind="foreach: messages">
    <li class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" alt="Generic placeholder image" src="~/content/img/chat/headshot1.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body chat-pop">
            <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="media">
        <a class="pull-right" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" alt="Generic placeholder image" src="~/content/img/chat/headshot2.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="pull-right media-body chat-pop mod"> 
            <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is a list containing two li-elements. Depending on if the `message` contains the word "admin" or the word "user" iw would like to render one or the other li-element.

So I have two questions.

1. How can I know if the message contains a specific substring?
2. How can I use this substring to render the specific `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="media-list chat-list" data-bind="foreach: messages">
    <li class="media" data-bind="visible:$data.indexOf('admin')>-1">
        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" alt="Generic placeholder image" src="~/content/img/chat/headshot1.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body chat-pop">
            <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="media" data-bind="visible:$data.indexOf('user')>-1">
        <a class="pull-right" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" alt="Generic placeholder image" src="~/content/img/chat/headshot2.jpg">
        </a>
        <div class="pull-right media-body chat-pop mod">
            <p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: visible property just hides the li. replace "visible" with "if" if you do not want to render it.